# zip the CSV exported file from database in spring batch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a batch that is run once starting my spring boot application (no launcher configured, just due to `spring.batch.job.enabled=true` my job is running).
The aim of my job is to export csv file from database.

I want to zip this file once the CSV file is created.
In which step i can zip it, I tried in in itemWriter and the zipped file is empty,

my source code is:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemWriter<User> writer(){
    log.info("start writing user ... ");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.SHORT).withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    Instant instant = Instant.now();
    date = formatter.format(instant);
    date = date.replaceAll("[/,\\s,:]", "-");
    FlatFileItemWriter<User> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<User>();
    filePath = config.getPath + date + ".csv";
    writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource (filePath));
    writer.setAppendAllowed(true);
    writer.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<User>() {
        {
            setDelimiter(",");
            setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<User>() {
                {
                    setNames(new String[] { "Id", "Name" });
                }
            });
        }
    });
    writer.close();

    try {
        File file = new File(config.getPath() + "\\" + date + ".zip");
        ZipOutputStream zop = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream (file));
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(filePath);
        zop.putNextEntry(entry);
        zop.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return writer;
}
```

Comment: You only add the filePath as a name to the zipentry, but no actual data, so the file is empty.

Answer (score 1):

> In which step i can zip it, I tried in in itemWriter and the zipped file is empty,

You need to create two steps:

- One that creates the file (chunk oriented step)
- Another one that zips it (tasklet step)

You configuration is incorrect. You don't need to call `writer.close`, Spring Batch will do it as part of the writer's lifecycle. What you need to do is declare a bean of type `ItemWriter` and move the zipping code to a different step. For example:

```
@Bean
public JdbcCursorItemReader<User> jdbcCursorItemReader() {
    // define and return the reader
}

@Bean
public FlatFileItemWriter<User> writer(){
    log.info("start writing user ... ");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.SHORT).withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    Instant instant = Instant.now();
    date = formatter.format(instant);
    date = date.replaceAll("[/,\\s,:]", "-");
    FlatFileItemWriter<User> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<User>();
    filePath = config.getPath + date + ".csv";
    writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource (filePath));
    writer.setAppendAllowed(true);
    writer.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<User>() {
        {
            setDelimiter(",");
            setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<User>() {
                {
                    setNames(new String[] { "Id", "Name" });
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return writer;
}

@Bean
public Step exportFile() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("exportFile")
            .chunk(100)
            .reader(jdbcCursorItemReader())
            .writer(writer())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step compressFile() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("compressFile")
            .tasklet(new Tasklet() {
                @Override
                public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                    try {
                        File file = new File(config.getPath() + "\\" + date + ".zip");
                        ZipOutputStream zop = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream (file));
                        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(filePath);
                        zop.putNextEntry(entry);
                        zop.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                }
            });
}
```

Then define a job with these steps in the right order.

Comment: thanks a lot for this answer. I really like it. Just for the step compressFile. do you mean to use StepBuilderFactory. StepBuilder("compressFile") is not known

Comment: Yes, use the `StepBuilderFactory`. I just wrote the sample with `StepBuilder` to show you how to proceed. I edited the sample with `StepBuilderFactory`.